# Sorting array by two criteria

Tags: arrays, sorting

Assume we have an array of arrays, where each inner array contains two integers:

```
[[65, 100], [70, 150], [56, 90], [75, 190], [60, 95], [68, 110]]
```

I want to be able to sort these arrays in such a way where the values in an array are less than the array the comes after it. I essentially want to sort by two criteria instead of one. Here is some sample data:

```
Input: [[65, 100], [70, 150], [56, 90], [75, 190], [60, 95], [68, 110]]
Output: [[56, 90], [60, 95], [65, 100], [68, 110], [70, 150], [75, 190]]
```

**Extra credit:**

How can I adapt this version of selection sort to sort this dataset using two criteria?

**Selection Sort**

```
function selectionSort(arr) {
  for (var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
    var minIndex = i;
    for (var k = i;k < arr.length;k++) {
      if (arr[minIndex] > arr[k]) {
        minIndex = k;
      }
    }
    swap(arr, i, minIndex);
  }
  return arr;
}

function swap(arr, i, k) {
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[k];
  arr[k] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your criteria? What if one value is higher but the other one is lower?

Comment: If an array has values which cannot adhere to the numeric sequence then it should be thrown out

Comment: So the sorting function should assume that both elements are in the same order? Then just compare `arr[minIndex][0]` with `arr[k][0]`. You don't need two criteria, since they're equivalent.